# jQuery select element but one child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply some CSS on an element and all children but one. That includes strings outside elements as well. It's a  tag I need to leave out of it, because I need to change the CSS on the  tag to something else. I cannot do this:

```
$("div *").not("h1")[...]
```

because it does not apply to the strings.

http://jsfiddle.net/P5EAs/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/P5EAs/1/ to see what I mean.

This is jQuery, so doing it with CSS does not work. I need to use **.css()**

Comment: The H1 is inheriting the styles from the parent DIV, as it should

Answer (score 1):

since `h1` is a child of `div` you need to find children and use not..
try this

```
$("div").children().not('h1').css("color","red");
```

or,

with simple CSS

```
div{color:red;}
h1{color:black;} //after div..
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Only CSS:

```
div{color:red;}
div h1{color:black;}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P5EAs/9/)

Only JS:

```
$("div").css("color", "red");
$("div h1").css("color", "black");
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P5EAs/10/)

Comment: :first? No thanks, mate. There are many h1 tags. I solved it however. Turns out that the CSS I wanted to do didn't work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").css("color","red").find("h1").css("color", "black");
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you could get is:

```
$("div > *:not(h1)").css("color", "red");
```

However this will ignore text that is not wrapped in an element

Answer (score 0):

You can not set color directly to textnodes, so you either have to set the red color on the parent, and specifically set the H1 to black color, or you'll have to wrap the textnode in a span, and set the red color on all children but the H1.

```
$('div').children(':not(h1)').css('color', 'red').end()
        .contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        }).wrap('<span style="color: red" />')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/P5EAs/6/)